# ssh-copy-id tool can't handle public identity_file when it has multiple dots in a filename

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

When using `-i` option and providing file like `admin_rsa.pem.pub` utility is trying to open admin_rsa.pem file.

Is it expected behavior?

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

By the option `-i` you (the client side) start a *key-authentcation*. This is done by proving, you have access to the *private key* by generating a signed token.

The server gets the token (signed by your private key) and verifies the signature by using the *public key* you have stored in your home at the server.

*=> To do this authentication job, the client has to access the private key (your `admin_rsa.pem`)*